# Cannot update a timestamp column after .Attach

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have this ASP.Net code and I was getting an error when running it. The error was:

> Server: Msg 272, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Cannot update a timestamp
>   column.

Here's the mapping for this table that I already have:

> Property(x =>
>   x.Version).HasColumnName(@"Version").IsOptional().HasColumnType("timestamp").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);

Note that I do have a version column in my table.

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put([FromBody]WordForm wordForm)
    {
        // SampleSentences -> s

        var oldsObj = db.SampleSentences
                    .Where(w => w.WordFormId == wordForm.WordFormId)
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .ToList();
        var newsObj = wordForm.SampleSentences.ToList();

        // There is other code here to modify SampleSentences
        //
        //

        // db.WordForms.Attach(wordForm);
        // db.Entry(wordForm).State = EntityState.Modified;
        wordForm.StatusId = (int)EStatus.Saved;
        await db.SaveChangesAsync(User, DateTime.UtcNow);
        return Ok(wordForm);
    }
```

**I was able to fix the error** by adding comments to the two lines in the method. But could someone explain why I am getting the error if I don't comment out those lines. Should I not be able to Attach the wordForm and mark as Modified?

Comment: `timestamp` is the deprecated name of `rowversion`. It has nothing to do with time

Comment: Add the `[TimeStamp]` attribute to the entity's rowversion property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your table probably has a `rowversion` or `timestamp` field which is used for optimistic concurrency. [rowversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) fields can't be set or updated at all. They are a value that gets incremented automatically each time a row is modified.

To avoid the problem, mark your `rowversion` property with the [TimeStamp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.timestampattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute:

```
[TimeStamp]
public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
```

In fact, `timestamp` is the **deprecated** name of the type which causes a bit of confusion

From the docs:

> The timestamp syntax is deprecated. This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.

Comment: I updated the question to show I already have mapping for that column so maybe there's something else with the way that I do the attach?